# Disable Back Button (showing cached version) without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net

I want to disable the broswer back button without using javascript.  So far i have used this coding:

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.CacheControl = "private"
Response.CacheControl = "public"
```

It's working fine in the internet explorer 8 but in case of mozilla fire fox it is not working.pls say  same the solution to work in all browsers.

Thanks in advance

With Regards
V.karthik

Comment: I'm correcting the title so this doesn't get unnecessary down-votes, since the no-caching you're after is perfectly valid...just "disabling the back button" you'll find is frowned upon, for good reason :)  But that's different from what you're after here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the response in this question:

[Best way to disable client caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985530/best-way-to-disable-client-caching)

It's the same question, the same problem (IE working, FF not), and an accepted solution. I'm quoting:

```
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Jun 2009 08:01:46 GMT (the actual modification date)
Cache-Control: store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

EDIT:

You can set the first two header like this in the codebehind of your page:

```
this.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
this.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
```

But actually, it should be enough to do the following to deactivate caching (see also [Whats the best way to deal with pages loaded via browser history in asp .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727382/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-pages-loaded-via-browser-history-in-asp-net)):

```
this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
this.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

This generates the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
```

Comment: where to use this coding same me in detail

Comment: how to use these coding and where to use

Comment: it is not working for mozila firefox3.6.3 and safari 4.0 pls help me to work in all browser.And Say codings where to use.i am struggling a lot.but it working fine in ie and google chrome.

Comment: You could use it in the Page_Load event handler for example. Please note that after a postback, you should redirect to an other page. See also http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/

Comment: i have used this coding in the page load event it is working only in ie
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(False)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()


in case of mozilla not working