# Refresh RadioButtonList in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I got this code for my RadioButtonList:

```
<div style="margin-top:5px"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList6" RepeatColumns = "2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table"  runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem ValidationGroup="Curriculum" style="margin-right:12px; margin-top:-10px" >Si</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem ValidationGroup="Curriculum" >No</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList></div>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
    ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList6" Text="Elige una opción" 
    ValidationGroup="Curriculum">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

It works just fine, problem is, when go to another page, if i click back, Radio Buttons keep selected, i need them to step back or 'refresh' when i go back to the form, just to be clear, my form is a 9 pages one, so when user clicks finished it goes to another page, but if user wants to go back, it appears to be still selected.

How can i solve this?

I hope i've explained myself, thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, yes, with textboxes, but i can edit them, so i think it's no problem there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to deal with pages loaded via browser history in asp .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727382/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-pages-loaded-via-browser-history-in-asp-net)

Comment: Can you just onload write something like RadioButtonList6.SelectedIndex = -1; So there will be nothing selected...

Comment: On class method you mean? @MishaZaslavsky

Comment: On code behind - c# code... where the method OnLoad or an Init method (if exists)

Comment: I think i should use an if statement then, "if RadioButtonList6.SelectedItem = true { RadioButtonList6.SelectedIndex = -1;}" ?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible. Is it working now?

Comment: I tried, but throws me error CS0200 '(' and ')' expected

Comment: Nevermind, i added an aditional 'back' button, and it refreshes automatically, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 
RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex=-1
properties of radiobutton list is listed below
use this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the documentation! It works now, but it's always good to go futher into concepts.